# Filter out entire group based on item ranking in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a table as shown below:

```
group   item    rank    
1       A        1  
1       B        2  
1       C        3  
2       A        2  
2       B        1  
3       A        1  
3       C        2
```

I want those groups data only, where item A has rank 1 as shown below:

```
group   item    rank    
1        A       1  
1        B       2  
1        C       3      
3        A       1  
3        C       2
```

In group 2, A has rank 2, therefore not a part of output.

Comment: You have simplified this so much that it doesn't make any sense. I would urge to read this question and ask yourself if you could understand it. And also decide which DBMS you are using. Then add the tag for the one you are actually using.

Comment: What's wrong with "select * from table where not (item = 'A' and rank = 1)"?

Comment: how 3, c, 2 is come to your output

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin 3,c,2 is in output, because corresponding to id 3, A has rank 1.

Comment: @JoshEller, I need those groups where item A has rank 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is using an `IN` clause

```
select *
from yourTable
where id in (select id from yourtable where item='A' and rank = 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use a subquery for get the involved  id and the join

```
select * from my_table m 
inner join  (
  select  distinct id 
  from  my_table  
  where  item = 'A' 
  and rank = 1 
) t on t.id = m.id
```